# Is it possible to place 100 hemispherical dimples of diameter 3 millimeters on a golf ball that is 3 centimeters in diameter?

Tags: geometry

In every way I think it's possible but the following pdf says not! It's making me crazy, if someone can give me a hint, please give.

[original problem](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/assignments/ps2b.pdf) (part II problem 1d)

Comment: Think in areas...

Comment: I thought in areas, no problem found! area of the golf ball is about 28 while the area removed by 100 dimples is about 7

Comment: @kptlronyttcn: The figures from your comments are cm², right? You might want to edit your post to include these figures and how you computed them, so people won't have to dig through comments to find that the most obvious reason apparently isn't enough.

Comment: The pdf is incorrect. If you pack the dimples tightly, the area outside the dimples will be smaller (quite a lot smaller) than the area taken by the dimples themselves. You correctly compute that the dimples will take approximately 7 cm², while the area of the ball itself is about 28 cm². You could probably fit 300 or more dimples on such a ball, but probably not 400.

Comment: To clarify what I said, by area outside the dimples I mean the area between the dimples packed tightly. If you put only 100 dimples on the ball, there will obviously be a lot of extra space left over, where you could add more dimples.

Comment: Actually one can only place 105 dimples. Because dimples have depth, and 1.5mm is a deep dimple for a ball with radius 1.5cm. Because sphere is not flat, each dimple will have a different orientation. So if there is not enough space between them they will go to each other from inside the ball. but still 105 is more than 100. But this is a problem set from MIT, on ocw. so probably it's solved during the real class in 2006 by many students. It's really not probable that the pdf is wrong.

Comment: I think I got it. In (c), it says "The numbers have been changed to protect the innocent." That is, 3cm and 3mm are not the numbers used in the middle school math contest exam. In (d), the phrase "With the diameters actually given..." refers to the numbers used in the contest, not the pdf. In the next sentence, "our golf ball" implies to the dimensions given in the pdf.

Comment: You are right about the depth of the dimples, but for the dimensions given the correction is quite small, so your 105 seems too small.

Comment: thanks, (and also yes 105 is not right, it was 305 but stachexchange didn't let me edit my comment.)